# Running multiple async unit test methods produces an error, but running them individually does not

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

In my WPF MVVM I have two **working when ran individually** unit tests which test two button command methods:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    // Arrange
    var interfaceStub = new StubInterface();
    interfaceStub.Method = () => "Message";
    var viewModel = new ViewModel(interfaceStub);

    // Act
    await Task.Run(() => viewModel.GenerateCommand.Execute());

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("Message", viewModel.Response);
}

[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethod2()
{
    // Arrange
    var interfaceStub = new StubInterface();
    interfaceStub.Method = () => "Message";
    var viewModel = new ViewModel(interfaceStub);

    // Act
    await Task.Run(() => viewModel.VerifyCommand.Execute());

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("Message", viewModel.Response);
}
```

`VerifyCommand` and `GenerateCommand` are actually of type `AsyncRelayCommand` which implements `ICommand`, thus they are `async void` and I have to run them on a separate thread in the test by using `Task.Run()`. `Method1` and `Method2` actually stands for the `ExecuteMethod1CommandAsync` and `ExecuteMethod2CommandAsync` commands used by buttons respectively.

Problem is, if I run these tests separately, they both pass. **However, once I try to test them both at the same time**, `Assert.AreEqual()` fails:

> Expected: <"Message"> , Actual <>

This is clearly because one of the tests doesn't wait for the thread to finish and the value is not yet returned at the assertion step. I added the `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);` to both test methods and then both tests passed when I ran them together again (which further proves this).

Why does running them individually makes the test methods to wait, but running them separately makes one of them to not wait?

EDIT: When I run them separately, the time it takes: ~140 ms both. When I run them together: the one that passes is ~140 ms again, the other which doesn't is only 90 ms (proves my findings)

EDIT 2: Execute method:

```
// Executes the action
public async void Execute(object parameter)
{
    // Do something

     try
     {
         await execute(parameter);
     }
     finally
     {
         // Do something
     }
}
```

`execute` is a `Func<object, Task>`. This is apparently where the problem occurs - when execute(parameter) is started, it instantly returns back to the Task in `TestMethod`. What's the best approach to solve this?

Comment: On Visual Studio in Test Explorer u have next to search input a button with "Run Tests in parallel". Delete `async` modifier and try this method to run unit tests in parallel mode.

Comment: @Sidron I can't delete async... I have to `await` for the task. Running in parallel doesn't help.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes that is exactly what happens, I just realised this a few minutes ago as I ran an infinite loop after and before the await in async void..

Comment: And in almost all circumstances, `await Task.Run()` is pointless. You're asking the TPL to find *some other thread* to run some code, and then announcing (with the `await`) - "well, there's nothing useful for *this* thread to do until that other work is finished". Cut out the middle man - use *your* thread to run that code.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever what if I need to run a function on UI thread? I found out in SO that Task.Run() and awaiting for it is how people achieve that? Oh, do you mean like that they should be one right after the other, so the purpose is to have something in between, like output to console?

Comment: Yes, the exception I'd generally make is - if you have a *CPU* bound action you need to perform where it doesn't need to access UI objects and you're currently executing in the UI context, *that* is when it's appropriate to `await Task.Run()`. (or other single threaded contexts). In most of my experience though, people use it without having considered whether it's appropriate.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever if you want, you can post the answer about the async void and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async void` means that there's no way for the caller to determine when that activity has completed. Wrapping it in `Task.Run()` doesn't change that. You now have a `Task` that starts something running and then its work is done so it's marked as complete despite the fact that the `async void` method it called may not yet have completed.

You're not going to fix this without some kind of re-design of the code. If you're constrained by external factors (interface/delegate signatures) to having these methods be `void`, consider whether whatever is on the other side will be expecting these methods to return when they've not finished. If that's the case, then unfortunately the best way forward is to undo the `async` stuff you've done there.

If there are no external factors, make the methods `async Task` instead so that you can directly `await` them (no need for `Task.Run`).

If there are external factors but you believe the contract allows you to return with work incomplete, then I'd recommend doubling the number of methods you have. Make one set by `async Task` and unit test these. Then have the `async void` methods be the *thinnest* possible wrapper that just calls the `async Task` version. (If you can accept that these wrappers will not be unit tested).

Comment: the wrapper thing is basically what I was looking for